# running javascript on php based loop

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create JavaScript based suggest input inside php based loop, this is my JavaScript code,

```
<script> 
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [ 
            <?php do { ?> "<?php echo $row_style['style']; ?>", <?php } 
            while($row_style = mysql_fetch_assoc($style)); ?>];

        $( "#style" ).autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
    });
</script>
```

this my html code,

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr><td>no</td><td>style</td></tr>
        <?php $no=1; for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++){?>   
        <tr><td><?php echo $no++ ?></td><td><input name="style" type="text"></td></tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</html>
```

It's working on first row, but not the second,third or fourth, 
what is going on with my code?

Comment: You are using the same id #style. You must use unique ids in case you want more elements

Comment: how can i create id #style same as id style in php loops?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
<?php
$style = '';
while($row_style = mysql_fetch_assoc($style)) {
    $style .= $row_style['style'].',';
}
$style = rtrim($style, ',');
?>

<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [<?php echo $style;?>];
    <?php for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++){?>
    $( "#style<?php echo $i;?>" ).autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
    <?php }?>
});
</script>

<html>
<table>
    <tr><td>no</td><td>style</td></tr>
    <?php $no=1; for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++){?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $no++ ?></td><td><input id="style<?php echo $i;?>" name="style" type="text"></td></tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
</html>
```

'#style' is replaced with '.style'.

Also your js array ended with ',', so now the ending coma is trimmed